# Debian Based Server not booting, soon after GRUB screen it restarts?

Tags: debian

I have tried running memtest, it start get about half way then abruptly restarts.

I assume this is not a problem with the OS itself but rather a hardware issue, I have checked various logs when after about 10 reboots it starts ok,

```
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/dmesg
```

All I get is:

```
EXT4-fs(sdc1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro restart
```

So I ran `fcsk` on the drive, to check if the fs was failing and it was fine.

Really don't know how to find why the server is continuosly restarting andif I get lucky it will boot up.

Answer (score 0):

Either the server motherboard or power supply is broken. More specifically, most likely the capacitors in either one are dead.

http://badcaps.net has pictures what dead capacitors look like. If your motherboard has capacitors like this, then that is the problem.